# Show that for each $v \in V$ exist $w \in W$ and $c \in \Bbb R$ unique such that $v=cv_0+v$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let be $V$ a vector space over the field of real numbers, $f \in V^*$ and $W=ker (f)$. If $v_0 \in V$ is a vector such that  $f(v_0)\neq0$, show that for each $v \in V$ exist $w \in W$ and $c \in \Bbb R$ unique such that $v=cv_0+v$

any idea or clue to how to proceed to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(v)=a$; then $f(v)=\frac{a}{f(v_0)}f(v_0)$, which implies
$$
v-\frac{a}{f(v_0)}v_0\in\ker f=W
$$
This provides existence. For the uniqueness, suppose
$$
v=cv_0+w=c'v_0+w'
$$
then
$$
(c-c')v_0=w'-w\in\ker f
$$
so $c=c'$, because $(c-c')f(v_0)=0$.